# 'window.onbeforeunload' works even when am refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Am using 'window.onbeforeunload' to call an event when browser closing. But it works even when I am refreshing the page. I want to avoid this event when page refreshing, it needs to work only when I close the browser.

Comment: check the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Comment: 1: Please use a spell checker and check your spelling when you type. 2. please look around before asking - had you spelled onbeforeunload correctly, SO would have suggested many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+onbeforeunload+close